# iphone sdk: initialization of a AVAudioRecorder returns nil

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I want to initialize a AVAudioRecorder with the aac Format. To do so, I use the following code:

```
soundFilePath = [soundFilePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"aac"];NSURL *url = 
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath isDirectory:FALSE];

NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 'aac '] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];                                     
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];                //Encoder Settings 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin] forKey:AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey];    //Sample Rate Conversion Settings

_recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:nil];
```

why doesn't this work? Id does work, if I change aac into ima4!

Answer (score 0):

'aac' is not among the predefined format ids and so it doesnot work.
U can have a look at the supported audiotype constants for getting a list of all these. They are availab [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004488-CH4-SW3)

at the Constants secion.