# AVAudioPlayer keeps crashing at this line? (initializing)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, memory-management, avaudiorecorder

My AVAudioPlayer keeps crashing at the error:nil line:

```
AVAudioRecorder *tempRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                                 initWithURL:nil
                                 settings:nil
                                 error:nil];
```

I tried setting it to a non-nil value, but still, it keeps crashing at that specific line!

Here's the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00e0ed65 in CFEqual ()
#1  0x00e69e86 in CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue ()
#2  0x0158cda8 in AudioFileFormatRegistry::GetTypesForExtension(__CFString const*, unsigned long*, void*) ()
#3  0x0158eb5c in AudioFileGetGlobalInfoSize ()
#4  0x00cc8e6a in -[AVAudioRecorder initWithURL:settings:error:] ()
#5  0x000033f7 in -[RecorderVC resetRecorder] at /Users/Ahmed/Documents/AudioRecorder/AudioRecorder/RecorderVC.m:52
#6  0x000031d3 in -[RecorderVC viewDidLoad] ()
#7  0x000c4089 in -[UIViewController view] ()
#8  0x000d6f54 in -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] ()
#9  0x000d5aaa in -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#10 0x000d78a2 in -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] ()
#11 0x000d7d5e in -[UITabBarController viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#12 0x001e82e9 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#13 0x017e1a5a in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#14 0x017e3ddc in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#15 0x017890b4 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#16 0x0178a294 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#17 0x000169c9 in -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] ()
#18 0x00016e83 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#19 0x00021617 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#20 0x00019abf in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#21 0x0001ef2e in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#22 0x01130992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#23 0x00ed8944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#24 0x00e38cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#25 0x00e35f83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#26 0x00e35840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#27 0x00e35761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#28 0x000167d2 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#29 0x00022c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#30 0x00002a39 in main ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass `nil` for `initWithURL:`.  See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not true.

Comment: In a completely different project, I am initializing AVAudioPlayer with nil setting and nil error, and it's recording just fine. (With no errors or warning)

Comment: AVAudioPlayer or AVAudioRecorder?

Comment: Sorry, I meant AVAudioRecorder.

Comment: You can see it here for example, this person is initializing it with nil error and it's working fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856058/iphone-sdk-initialization-of-a-avaudiorecorder-returns-nil 
I will try to find an example with nil settings...

Comment: No, it's set to a url. In both bases, my URL is an actual value.

Comment: For the nil settings case, you can see it here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1owyPl9BfZk skip to 39:11

Comment: In your posted example, it says `nil` for `initWithURL:`.  I think that would produce the error you're seeing in the stack trace.